# dev.example.com Frontend Login Creates Sessions for example.com (Can't login)

Tags: login, session, cookie

I have two Magento 1.9.0.1 sites. One on `example.com` and one on `dev.example.com`

**Production:**

*Cookie Path:* (none)

*Cookie Domain:* `example.com`

**Development:**

*Cookie Path:* `/`

*Cookie Domain:* `dev.example.com`

I've cleared the `/var/session/` directory from the development site, cleared the `/var/cache/` directory, and removed any any all `*.example.com` cookies from my browser. As soon as I hit the homepage of the development site I get new cookies for both `example.com` and `dev.example.com`

The problem is that this is causing the famous "Can't login on the frontend" bug. Magento is seeing both cookies and cookies it should be reading.

Things I've tried to do to debug:

1. Checked Default vs Website vs Store settings. The development server always has `dev.example.com` for it's settings, while the production server always has `example.com`
2. Checked the frontend for iframes or other content loading `example.com` from `dev.example.com` Chrome Inspector shows nothing loading the production domain from the development site.
3. I've also checked the usual stuff, like making sure that the form_key is present, etc. This is definitely an issue of Magento creating a session/cookie using the wrong domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.example.com` as a cookie domain means it'll take any cookie that contains `.example.com` in the domain. The only way to fix this would be to also specify a subdomain for the live webshop. For example; user `.www.example.com` as the cookie domain.

Comment: My understanding is that only `.example.com` (with the leading dot) would match all subdomains. If I leave the leading dot out of my settings on production, (as I have done,) shouldn't this only match the literal `example.com`?

Comment: As far as I know without a leading . can only be accomplished by setting a cookie directly with `header()`. PHPs cookie method always prefixes the domain with a dot

Comment: This doesn't explain the following: Clear ALL cookies having to do with example.com and any of it's subdomains. Then, visit dev.example.com and note in Chrome that a new cookie has been created for example.com and dev.example.com. It shouldn't create cookies for two domains, should it?

Comment: @TylerV. hmmm you got me there. That's weird indeed